# navigation browser goto

Tags: c#, watin

Hello I am working with watin and and trying to open url but I am getting follwoing exception:

> at WatiN.Core.IE.CreateNewIEAndGoToUri(Uri uri, IDialogHandler
>   logonDialogHan dler, Boolean createInNewProcess)    at
>   WatiN.Core.IE..ctor()    at WatinTesting.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   in c:\users\admin\documents\visua l studio
>   2010\Projects\WatinTesting\WatinTesting\Program.cs:line 20

The code earlier working fine.
Please let me know what is going wrong : In case please let me know the alternative code that I can use for the same using type : Browser

The C# code is as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WatiN.Core;
using WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer;
using System.Threading;

namespace WatinTesting
{
    class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {               

                IE browser = new IE();
                    browser.GoTo("http://google.com");
                    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
                    browser.Button(Find.ByValue("Google Search")).Click();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add missing data like watin version and is the browser instance created (IE instance).

Maybe this will help try to create the IE instance with this parameters:

```
IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com", true); //first param is url and the second is new process
```